# Can you get Mink to follow redirect from https to http and keep the Session?

Tags: php, symfony, acceptance-testing, mink, goutte

I am trying to test my ajax scripts using codeception & PhpBrowser(which uses Mink with Goutte driver).

My ajax scripts require an authenticated session in order to execute, and the session is created via my log in page.

I am having issues with getting the PhpBrowser/Link sessions, to persist after login.

I created a PhpBrowser Helper function to overwrite _initialize so I could get https working with a self signed cert on my test server like this:

```
public function _initialize()
{
    $client = new \Behat\Mink\Driver\Goutte\Client();
    $driver = new \Behat\Mink\Driver\GoutteDriver($client);

    $curl_config = array_merge($this->curl_defaults, $this->config['curl']);
    array_walk($curl_config, function($a, &$b) { $b = "curl.$b"; });
    $curl_config['ssl.certificate_authority']=false;
    $client->setClient(new \Guzzle\Http\Client('', $curl_config));
    $client->followRedirects(true);
    $this->session = new \Behat\Mink\Session($driver);
    \Codeception\Util\Mink::_initialize();
}
```

Now when I run my acceptance test it seems like the Login works correctly, and the redirect happens based on the apache access_logs, but the PHPSESSID cookie does not persist, so all of my access request after login are unauthorized.

I tried testing this in acceptance test by comparing the

```
$I->getCurrentUrl()
$I->getResponseHeaders()
```

before and after the redirect.

The currentUrl() return value never gets to the redirect destination, although apache access_logs say otherwise.

getResponseHeaders() returns a PHP_SESSID cookie after the form submission, but it does not exist for all requests after.

Any ideas/guesses why the session created during login is not persisting after the redirect?

Do I need to do any special configuration to Mink sessions to get them to follow the redirect, or am I doing something else wrong?

Thanks in advance for your help!

-Ed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally figured out the issue.

I had to explicitly set the cookie to be saved for the /Guzzle/Http/Client object in my overwritten _initialize function.

```
public function _initialize()
{
    $client = new \Behat\Mink\Driver\Goutte\Client();
    $driver = new \Behat\Mink\Driver\GoutteDriver($client);
    $cookiePlugin = new \Guzzle\Plugin\Cookie\CookiePlugin(new \Guzzle\Plugin\Cookie\CookieJar\ArrayCookieJar());

    $curl_config = array_merge($this->curl_defaults, $this->config['curl']);
    array_walk($curl_config, function($a, &$b) { $b = "curl.$b"; });
    $curl_config['ssl.certificate_authority']=false;
    $guzzle_client = new \Guzzle\Http\Client('', $curl_config);
    $guzzle_client->addSubscriber($cookiePlugin);

    $client->setClient($guzzle_client);
    $client->followRedirects(true);
    $this->session = new \Behat\Mink\Session($driver);
    \Codeception\Util\Mink::_initialize();
}
```